# How to use php str_word_count to count words in a textarea

Tags: php, textarea

I am in an entry level php course. The lesson is to create an HTML page with a textarea submit form in the essence of charging a customer for a classified ad using the number of words as the cost. That part is complete. The second page is a php script using str_word_count. How do you count the words in a textarea and then charge a price per word for every word over a set number?

Comment: Have you looked at the manual page for str_word_count() yet? What problem are you actually having?

Comment: read this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_word_count.asp

Comment: and this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Comment: yes looked at the manual. i don't know the proper syntax to get the script to count the words and than some how take that number and use it in an if else statement to generate a cost for the customer.

Comment: mr.soroush - w3schools is too full of errors and inaccuracies to be a good site every to point anybody too

Answer (score 2):

Here's the doc for [**`str_word_count`**](http://php.net/str_word_count)

Using it is really easy. For example if your textarea is named "`mytextarea`" and you sent the form via POST (`<form method="POST">`), your textarea data will be in`$_POST['mytextarea']`

Then counting the words :

```
$count = str_word_count($_POST['mytextarea']);
```

Then you just have to use the $count variable to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var =textareaObject.value ; //Store textarea text in $var 

print_r(str_word_count($var));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just use `$words= str_word_count($_POST['clientdetails']);`
then, probably just do a simple maths like

`$fee =  $words * 0.50;`

0.50 is the amount of money you are going to charge

then, something like:

`<?php echo 'we are going to charge you '.$fee.' for these words'; ?>`